# Render variable partial

Tags: handlebars.js, require-handlebars

I'm using Handlebars together with BackboneJS. I have Backbone Views that extend each other, e.g. a `ModalView` and a `SpecificModalView`. `ModalView` has a Handlebar template, something like this (simplified):

```
<div class="modal-header">
    {{modalTitle}}
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{modalBody}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    {{modalFooter}}
</div>
```

Now, the `modalBody` is usually a bit more complex than just a regular placeholder like the title and is defined by the `SpecificModalView`. What I want is that the SpecificModalView can override the `modalBody` with a partial or an `HTMLElement` object.

Is this beyond the scope of Handlebarjs and should I just use jQuery to find the modal-body and replace it's content with whatever is passed as `modalBody`? Or can Handlebarjs deal with variable partials and HTMLElements?

One idea I tried was that `SpecificModalView` registered a helper called `modalBody` and returned whatever body required for that modal. The return value of helpers seems to be type casted to a string though.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just found one solution, you can return HTML from a helper with the `Handlebars.SafeString` object. So the `SpecificModalView` can do something like this:

```
hbs.registerHelper('modalBody', function() {
    var tpl = require('hbs!templates/SpecificModalBody'),
    return new hbs.SafeString(tpl());
});
```

(I'm using requirejs)
This offers the flexibility of creating an HTML object with jQuery or using another Handlebar template for the content.

I'm open to any other solutions though.